# TCPClient async/await C#

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, асинхронность, tcpclient

У меня есть несколько девайсов. Программа должно эти устройства постоянно пинговать.

Столкнулся с проблемой - если соединение пропадает, то моя программа ничего не выводит, кроме первого опроса перед пропадание соединения, а если восстановить соединение, то через секунд 15 программа начнет выводить данные.

Мне нужно чтобы выводились постоянно и неудачные попытки соединения.

```
public async Task Start(string ip)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("Begin");
        textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        int i = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            watch.Restart();
            using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
            {
                tcp.SendTimeout = 1000;
                try
                {
                    await tcp.ConnectAsync("192.168.127.23", 10001);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Debug.Assert(!tcp.Connected);
                }

                watch.Stop();
                if (tcp.Connected)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(i.ToString() + ") " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
                    textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}) Offline", i));
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Вот так это происходит.

[image: Вот так это происходит]

Comment: `Получилось так` - классно, в чем проблема тогда?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - в теории так не должно было получиться... если нет соединения, то выводится Offline каждый раз.

Comment: Простите, а что она должна выводить? Задержку? Ну так вынесите ее в блок `else` и выводите. `если соединение пропадает, то моя программа ничего не выводит` - она должна вам выдать `textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}) Offline", i));` Вот я например сделал тестовый сервер, запустил ваш код, вывод сделал в консоль, [получил это](https://pastebin.com/YHdBdimV). Вроде отработало как вы ей и сказали.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ добавил гифку, как у меня выводятся данные. Чутка обрезал, чтобы долго не было.